# CSS filter in firefox not rendering

Tags: css, firefox

Im wondering how to apply the filter property in firefox. I cant seem to match the value i need so far..

```
.img-holder>img{
filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'900\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0.5); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(2, 85, 165, 0.36);
-moz-box-shadow: rgba(2, 85, 165, 0.36);
}
```

Comment: filters normally don't work in firefox depends on the version.  But what are you trying to do with the filter?

Comment: You might need this... [CSS Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

Answer (score 0):

try this !! **filter property in firefox perfectly working** :)

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
```

Good Luck!

Comment: I have this.. but the grayscale is not rendering the same way as in chrome or safari